# My whole layout changed color when working on a component in MUI React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

whenever I add the paper widget my whole screen turns white

```
const FqaWidget = () => {
  return (
    <Widget>
   <Paper>
      <Box>
       
      </Box>
      </Paper>
    </Widget>
  );
};
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qOTP.png)

Comment: Going to need some context here. Does anything appear in the console? How are those components styled? What happens when you add content inside `Box`?

Comment: That means, one of the components haven't been called properly or missing some dependancies inside the component, if you post your console message then it will be much easier to guide you more.

Comment: This is exactly what `<Paper />` is: it's meant as a container that provides a paper-like background to its contents. And by default that paper's color is white.

Comment: Thank you I had just forgotten to add my theme over the widget so the paper wouldn't override my theme! Thanks again your comments helped me.